# Is there a robust Identity-Based Digital Signature algorithm?

Tags: signature, identity-based-encryption

I'm looking for a IB-DS algorithm in the web. I found [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLS_digital_signature) (if you know some other let me know). But I cannot figure out what the "identity" is. Better: I don't know if, in the section **Key Generation**, the $x$ is the identity. E.g. $x = H(EncodedBiometrics)$ (biometrics or any information publicly and inherently linked to the user) for some CRHF $H$. Can you confirm this or am I completely misunderstanding such a scheme (not necessairly this particular scheme but a generic IB-DS scheme)? I hope I've been clear